# How to call button height in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am trying to call a button height so I can dynamically set the y position equal to view that way dynamically the size will be constant. i can't find how to call the height. I am trying to do something like this:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.blurryVeiw.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (screenHeight - **buttion height**), width: screenWidth, height: 400)
    }) { (finished) in

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have a `UIButton` called `myButton`. You can get it's height by `myButton.frame.size.height`

Answer (score 0):

If “blurryView” is your button then you are specifying your button height as 400 when you set the frame, so use 400 for **buttonHeight**.
If it’s not, then you can use 
**button**.frame.height

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension of UIView

```
extension UIView {

    public var height: CGFloat {
        get
        {
            return self.frame.size.height
        }
    }

    public var width: CGFloat {
        get
        {
            return self.frame.size.width
        }
    }
}
```

when you want to use

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton()
let height = button.height
```

Because UIButton is based on UIView. So, UIButton can use extension of UIView